# Query changed records in SQL using a created / modified time stamp column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query my SQL Server 2008 R2 database to find out records that were put into a cancelled state during a given time period. Each record consist of one row in the database with a `Created By` timestamp, and a `modified by` timestamp. I can't change the schema of the database.

Each record has a "cancel state" column that is set to 0 or 1 (N and Y). I need to run a nightly job/query that will show all of the cancelled records from the day.

Simple enough, when the record is cancelled the modified timestamp is updated, so my query looks like

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM mytable 
 WHERE CONVERT(DATE, a.modified_timestamp) = CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
   AND cancel_flag = '1'
```

The issue I am running into, if any other data is modified in the record, the timestamp is updated so the query will give me duplicate results if some other value in the row is changed. Is there an easy way to do this without changing the schema or adding my own table for tracking?

Comment: Looks like you could try using [Change Data Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/cc645937.aspx). Otherwise, no, you'd need to change your schema/logic.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a lot easier to use this table for what you want if you had a `cancel_timestamp` rather than just a `cancel_flag`.  Do you have a history table or something that shows the prior versions of a record?